# MySQL, fulltext search to show last updated rows

Tags: php, mysql, database, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

I want to know how can I combine fulltext search query with additional clause to show the last updated rows first.

I have a database - `advertisements` and that table has many fields one of which is 'title'. I search this column with fulltext search.

Example DB:

1. Row with title:  Juniour PHP Developer
2. Row with title:  Seniour PHP Developer
3. Row with title:  C++ Developer

If I search my website e.g.:

"PHP Developer" -> then the resultset will be

- Juniour PHP Developer
- Seniour PHP Developer
- C++ Developer

Which is good.

However I need to extend this to return the last updated accurate results.
I have `updated_at` column in the DB.

E.g. when I search my website, I want to get results like:

"PHP Developer" -> then the resultset I want should be:

1. First to show 'PHP Developers' but to show the last updated ones first
2. Then to show every other developers (e.g. c++ developers) and they also has to be in order with the last updated ones first

I want the results to be like (when searching for "PHP Developer"):

1. Juniour `PHP Developer` - e.g. updated_at column =`13.02.16`
2. Seniour `PHP Developer` - updated_at=`10.02.16`
3. Juniour `PHP Developer` - updated_at=`04.01.16`
4. C++ `Developer` - updated_at=`13.02.16`
5. Java `Developer` - updated_at=`02.02.15`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You could use an order by on the `updated_at` column like

```
<your-query-here>
order by updated_at asc
```

Or you could create some kind of derived order and order by on that, like

```
<your-query-here>    
order by
    (
        case
            when <something> then 1
            when <something-else> then 2
            ...
        end
    ) asc
```

Comment: If I search for "PHP Developer" - when I use `ORDER BY updated_at` the problem is when "C++ Developer" has the latest `updated_at` value -> then the c++ comes first, which is not relevant, because php devs should be first.

Comment: have you tried anything involving case in the order by? you could use something like: order by (case when upper(title) like '%<search query>%' then 1 else 0 end) desc, updated_at asc